# Obtaining a list of all hyperlinks?

Tags: microsoft-office

Is there some method by which a list of all hyperlinks in a Microsoft Office 2010 Document can be obtained?

I'm trying to check a large number of large documents (a grab bag of Word, Excel and PowerPoint documents) for broken links, and I'd rather not have to read every line of every document to verify that I have a list of all links.

Answer (score 10):

For MS WORD,

```
 Press Alt + F9 to display the fields

Ctrl + F to open the search box

Search: ^d hyperlink

Check "Highlight all items found ..."

Click on the Find All button

Close the dialog

Ctrl + C to copy everything that is highlighted

Open a new document and paste.
```

For Excel,

```
Close all workbooks except the one you want to find the links in.
On the Edit menu, click Find.
Click Options.
In the Find what box, enter [.
In the Within box, click Workbook.
In the Look In box, click Formulas.
Click Find All.
In the box at the bottom, look in the Formula column for formulas that contain [.
To select the cell with a link, select the row in the box at the bottom.
Links are also commonly used in names, text boxes, or chart titles.
```

Comment: This works most excellently for Word; but what of Excel and PowerPoint?

Comment: You can use macro in excel. I have edited the answer. Plz do check.

Comment: The Excel answer doesn't really answer the question: What I need is to rapidly ascertain whether or not a document contains any hyperlinks, anywhere.

Comment: edited answer..

Comment: Unfortunately, near as I can tell, the Excel answer doesn't work.

Comment: This gives me a list of the anchor texts in Word. To get the URLs, I turn on wildcards and search for http[!\"]{1,} in the search step.

Comment: Displaying the field codes (not the same as paragraph marks) is necessary. Then search for the word 'hyperlink'.

Answer (score 1):

To list all hyperlinks in a Word document:

```
Sub CheckLinks()
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To doc.Hyperlinks.Count
        Debug.Print doc.Hyperlinks(i).Address & " " & doc.Hyperlinks(i).SubAddress
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not get my version of Microsoft Word (2013) to show me the options in the accepted answer. This was the only approach that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I really found the answer of @user228546 helpful, as I could not get my version of Microsoft Word (2013) to show me the options in the accepted answer. However, it's a little brief, and it requires a good knowledge of Visual Basic for Applications ([VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)) to get everything to work.

Here's a slightly modified answer that could help some people who don't know so much about VBA.

You'll need to get to the VBA editor using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. Use "Insert" `->` "Module" up at the top, which will get you an editor window.

---

#### Get the Link Addresses in a New Document

I'm actually going to save the extracted hyperlinks into a new document, which I'll then save.

Type (or copy/paste) the following into the editor window.

```
Sub GetLinksInNewDoc()
'
' Finds all hyperlinks (even with strange formats,
' as long as they're active)
' and displays them in a new document.
'
    ' Declare the types of our variables
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim newDoc As Document
    Dim hlink As Hyperlink

    ' Use the script on the current document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    ' Open a new document to put the link addresses into
    Set newDoc = Documents.Add

    ' Loop through all the hyperlinks using the iterable hlink variable
    With doc
        For Each hlink In .Hyperlinks
            ' Switch into the new document
            newDoc.Activate

            ' Put the Hyperlink Address in the new document
            With Selection
                .InsertAfter hlink.Address & " " & hlink.SubAddress
                .InsertAfter vbNewLine
            End With
        Next hlink
    End With

    Set doc = Nothing
    Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Make sure that your Document with the hyperlinks is the last Microsoft Word document you had highlighted. Save your code. Either click on the green arrow to run, or from the upper toolbar select "Run" `->` "Run Sub/UserForm", or press <kbd>F5</kbd>

Note that you might get a "grey ghost" of the text that will eventually be in the document - something like

[image: Grey Ghost example]

---

#### Get the Link Addresses in a TXT File

Now, if you actually wanted to save the URLs to a `TXT` file, which is what got me to this question, you can use the same procedure, except your code should be

```
Sub GetLinksInTxtFile()
'
' Finds all hyperlinks (even with strange formats,
' as long as they're active)
' and outputs them to a TXT file.
' The TXT file will be written in the same directory
' as the original document
'
    ' Declare the types of our variables
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim hlink As Hyperlink

    ' Use the script on the current document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    ' Get a text file ready to which you will write the URLs
    ' Some old-school BASIC
    Open doc.Path & "\the_urls.txt" For Output As #1

    ' Loop through all the hyperlinks using the iterable hlink variable
    With doc
        For Each hlink In .Hyperlinks
            Print #1, hlink.Address & " " & hlink.SubAddress
        Next hlink
    End With

    Close #1
    Set doc = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hope it helps.

---

[Source](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/2-quick-ways-batch-extract-hyperlinks-word-document/) for my understanding, outline of copying into new document.

[Another related source](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1411-word-select-copy-all-hyperlinks.html)

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46963205/6505499) for writing to a text file (which is what I originally came searching for)

Answer (score 1):

Use LibreOffice and the Navigator pane. You can view all kinds of things from the doc including Hyperlinks

Comment: Explaining how to do this will make it an answer. Currently it is only a possibly helpful comment. Use the EDIT button to fix this.